# Exe of my Python program (PyInstaller) runs well from cmd prompt but crashes when double-clicked in Explorer

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have a Python script (Anaconda3 / Spyder 4) that runs fine in the Spyder IDE. With PyInstaller I generate a .exe (single file option). I can run this from the cmd prompt and it runs fine, too. However, if I run it by double-clicking on the exe in Windows Explorer, it starts running fine (I can specify an input file and perform certain simple actions), but then, when it starts processing my data, it crashes without any error message. The window just disappears. I managed to narrow the problem down (using print statements) to a numpy call (numpy.dot). Before this statement is reached, other numpy calls have already been executed succesfully (numpy.array and numpy.zeros).
I cannot find any suspect warnings in the PyInstaller warning log. I suspect that it has to do with search paths and that this depends on how the exe is started, but I have no idea how to:

- find out what really is going wrong and what the (root) cause could be
- what to try further to solve this problem
  Any pointers or (partial) solutions would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Try running your file from `cmd` in parent directory. So if it is about file paths, you can see what's wrong. `python3 parent_dir\myfile.py`

Comment: thanks for your response! If I do as you said, it immediately starts complaining that it cannot find the .ui file. (if I do this from the source directory itself, it works)

Comment: So you have found the problem. You need to modify your program such that it does not depend relative file paths.

Comment: but even in the crashing version (run from Explorer), numpy is found (as numpy.array and numpy.zeros did run correctly). And how can I change an import (of numpy) so that it uses absolute paths? (I did use the 'resource_path' solution for e.g. the ui file and icons and such, as recommended in other posts)